# What's the path for twig extends?

Tags: twig

I am not using symphony, just twig.

My structure:

```
root
 - assets
  - Twig (library)
 - templates
  - main_template.twig
  - child_template.twig
```

my main_template.twig is rendering just fine, but is unable to find the child_template.twig which is in the same folder.

I have tried using relative / full path but I can't the child_template to load. What's the path supposed to be? Do I need to do anything else besides adding the following to the child template? (and adding the blocks?)

```
{% extends "child_template.twig" %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `path` starts relative from the one you have provided in the loader of `twig`

<kbd>config.php</kbd>

```
require_once '/path/to/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem(__DIR__ . '/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
```

<kbd>child.twig.html</kbd>

```
{% extends "main_template.twig" %}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.

Comment: I still can't get it to work, and now I have the path relative to the loader. Is there a way to make it throw an error? I can't see any errors, so I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: To turn on twig's debug mode `$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true));`

Comment: I did. But it doesn't throw any errors. So I decided to see if it was path issue. I tried using "include" instead of "extends". The include works. It finds the template and it renders it. Do I need to render the templates I want to extend ahead of time?

Comment: Once a template extends from another, it can't have content outside a `block` element. Perhaps that is the problem. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twig/2922/template-inheritance/9907/using-a-base-template#t=201609192123358936159) what I mean. You need to define blocks in the parent template and override these in the child when required

Comment: I remove all white space... that's the only content I head outside the block. Nothing renders. I give up for now. I am just going to use include until I figure out the issue.